# Magento 2: Authorize.Net Not Creating The Order After Order Placed

Tags: magento2, orders, payment, authorize.net, magento2.2.9

I am working on a Magento 2.2.9 project and using Authorize.net accept.js payment gateway (default Magento Module).

However, the website is working fine but the issue is, when a customer place an order (sometimes on random cases), after the payment process it is not creating the order in Magento admin. I have checked the payment logs before order place and the data inside log is correct.

Kindly help me how do I get to resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have added the patch of authorize.net recently released one?
Is it showing any error popup after place order?

Comment: Hi @GauravJain! Thank you for looking into this. We are using AcceptJs payment method which is coming in latest Magento version 2.2.9

Answer (score 2):

@Sanchit I've used Authorize.net Accept JS payments on our website and have faced the same issues.

After debugging, I've found that the SHA512 key is not matched with the generated transaction key. The issue is because of the Float value of the transaction amount.

[Magento 2.X credit card Authorize.net using as set sandbox after place order but checkout page getting error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284539/magento-2-x-credit-card-authorize-net-using-as-set-sandbox-after-place-order-but/284723#284723)

It seems like the issue is with the Magento's core module of AcceptJs payments. I've disabled the AcceptJs payments and enabled the Direct Post payments from the admin and the orders are coming fine.

Hope it helps you to fix the order issue.

Comment: Hi Sumit, thank you so much for looking into it. Ok, let me give it a try.

Comment: Hi Sumit, I have checked it with SHA512 as you suggested but still facing the same issue. However, I have tried it with Direct Post then it is working fine.

Comment: But in the Magento admin, Direct post is showing "deprecated" so not sure how long it will go?

Comment: Hi Sanchit, You can use the Direct post payments as an alternative for now or you can go with the Paradoxlab Authorize.net solutions for the same.

Comment: Hi Sumit! although I have shifted to again DirectPost but the issue is still occurred with AcceptJS. I will Paradoxlab Authorize.net solutions. Well, thank you for your time and support.

Comment: Could you provide details on how to determine if the SHA512 key is not matched with the generated transaction key @Sumit? I'm facing this identical issue and after reviewing module-authorizenet-acceptjs/Gateway/Validator/TransactionHashValidator.php, I believe we might be experiencing this same thing. Thank you.

Comment: @sparecycle I've debugged it and shared my findings under https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284539/magento-2-x-credit-card-authorize-net-using-as-set-sandbox-after-place-order-but/284723#284723.