# Magento 2.X credit card Authorize.net using as set sandbox after place order but checkout page getting error

Tags: checkout, error, magento2.3.1, authorize.net, sandbox-mode

I am using Magento2.3.1 and I have to use payment method credit card authorize.net and right now I set payment method as sandbox mode after place order all fillup information correctly but getting the issue on the checkout page

```
An error occurred during processing. Please try again.
```

In console getting this error on network response is

```
{"messages":{"resultCode":"Error","message":[{"code":"E00001","text":"An error occurred during processing. Please try again."}]}}
```

below my configuration setting share with you

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check exception log file at root/var/ folder

Comment: not getting any error on log

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue with Authorize.net AcceptJs payments in Sandbox mode.

After debugging, I've found that the `SHA512` key is not matched with the generated transaction key. The issue is because of the Float value of the transaction amount.

I've fixed this issue by overriding the `generateSha512Hash()` of the AcceptJs core module in my custom module.

```
private function generateSha512Hash(
    string $merchantKey,
    string $merchantApiLogin,
    string $amount,
    string $transactionId
): string {
    if($amount == floor($amount)){
        $message = '^' . $merchantApiLogin . '^' . $transactionId . '^' . $amount . '^';
    } else {
        $message = '^' . $merchantApiLogin . '^' . $transactionId . '^' . (float)$amount . '^';
    }

    return strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha512', $message, pack('H*', $merchantKey)));
}
```

Hope this helps.